# How Do I Enable PHP Extensions (Windows, Drupal, MAMP)?

Tags: php, windows, drupal, mamp

I'm on Windows 11, trying to install Drupal 9 after installing and running MAMP. I'm getting the following error when I reach the "Verify requirements" step for Drupal's installation:

"**PHP EXTENSIONS**

Disabled

Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list (see the system requirements page for more information):

- gd"

When searching how to fix this, I was only able to find solutions related to WAMP and XXAMP. I've looked through every PHP.INI file in the "MAMP/conf" folder (there is a folder for each version of PHP), and every single one already had "extension=php_gd2.dll" without the semicolon in front, so I'm not sure why I keep getting this error when I attempt to install Drupal 9.

Comment: find your `PHP.ini` and find the line where it says `;extension=php_gd2.dll` and remove the `;`

Comment: @zimorok, thank you. As you can see in my original post, I already made that attempt for every PHP version folder for MAMP, and there were no semicolons to remove, yet the error persists.

Comment: you can check which `php.ini` being used with `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 5):

Open your php.ini file and search "gd" enable it like this

;extension=gd (Remove ";" and save file) "extension=gd"

Save file and Restart apache & check  phpinfo();

http://www.webassist.com/tutorials/Enabling-the-GD-library-setting

https://php.watch/versions/8.0/gd2-gd-windows

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a new line "*extension=php_**gd**.dll*" (not gd2.dll) to the **php.ini** [in the end of 'Dynamic Extensions' part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbEMc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow *steps*:

- Search for the line `; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.`
- 4 lines beneath this remove the semicolon from the line

  ```
  extension_dir = "ext"
  ```

  also, `restart Apache`